# Detect natural scrolling in X11

Tags: x11, ubuntu-22.04

I'm writing a C++ application that has an X11 Window.
Scrolling generates ButtonPress events with Button4 and Button5 as mouse wheel up and down respectively.

However, when I enable Natural Scrolling within my Ubuntu settings, those events get switched around. I.e. a mouse wheel up generates a Button 5 instead of 4.

That's all fine, but I have some elements in my application that I don't want to be affected by natural scrolling.
I need to be able to detect if the mouse event I got is a natural scrolling event.

On MacOS, I use [event isDirectionInvertedFromDevice] for this, but I can't find any documentation on how to programmatically check if a scroll event is inverted in X11.